# WCF Client Endpoint

Tags: wcf, workflow-foundation-4, endpoint

I have a WCF Service that works correctly and I cannot change. But on my client side (which is Workflow based) I would like the Address to be dynamic, so what I have done is created a new TestCustomEndpoint such as

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Configuration;
using System.ServiceModel.Description;
using System.Web;

namespace WorkflowService1
{
    public class TestEndpoints : ServiceEndpoint
    {
        public TestEndpoints(ContractDescription contract)
            : base(contract)
        {
            this.Binding = new NetTcpBinding();
            ResetBindingConfiguration(this.Binding);
            this.IsSystemEndpoint = false;
        }
        private void ResetBindingConfiguration(dynamic binding)
        {
            binding.SendTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
            binding.MaxReceivedMessageSize = Int32.MaxValue;
            binding.MaxBufferSize = Int32.MaxValue;
        }
    }

    public class TestEndpointsElementCollectionElement :
            StandardEndpointCollectionElement<TestEndpoints,
              TestEndpointsElement>
    {
    }

    public class TestEndpointsElement : StandardEndpointElement
    {
        protected override ServiceEndpoint CreateServiceEndpoint(ContractDescription contractDescription)
        {
            return new ServiceEndpoint(contractDescription);
        }

        protected override Type EndpointType
        {
            get { return typeof(TestEndpoints); }
        }

        protected override void OnApplyConfiguration(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, ServiceEndpointElement serviceEndpointElement)
        {
            endpoint.Address = new System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress("http://foo/bar/Automation.svc");
        }

        protected override void OnApplyConfiguration(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, ChannelEndpointElement channelEndpointElement)
        {
            endpoint.Address = new System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress("http://foo/bar/Automation.svc");
        }

        protected override void OnInitializeAndValidate(ServiceEndpointElement serviceEndpointElement)
        {
        }

        protected override void OnInitializeAndValidate(ChannelEndpointElement channelEndpointElement)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

and my web.config looks as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>

    <appSettings>
        <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
    </appSettings>
    <system.web>
        <compilation debug="true" strict="false" explicit="true" targetFramework="4.5" >
        </compilation>
        <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"/>
    </system.web>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <extensions>
            <endpointExtensions>
                <add name="TestCustomEndpoint" type="WorkflowService1.TestEndpointsElementCollectionElement,WorkflowService1" />
            </endpointExtensions>
        </extensions>
        <bindings>
            <basicHttpBinding>
                <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IProjectConfigurationsService" />
                <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IAutomation"/>
            </basicHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint
              binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IAutomation" kind="TestCustomEndpoint"
              contract="IAutomation" name="BasicHttpBinding_IAutomation" />
        </client>
        <behaviors>
            <serviceBehaviors>
                <behavior>
                    <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the values below to false before deployment -->
                    <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
                    <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
                    <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
                </behavior>
            </serviceBehaviors>
        </behaviors>
        <protocolMapping>
            <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
        </protocolMapping>
        <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />

    </system.serviceModel>
    <system.webServer>
        <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    </system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

but when i call the workflow template with one of the activities i get the following error.

```
Invalid endpoint type for endpoint extension configuration object.  This endpoint extension manages configuration of endpoint type 'WorkflowService1.TestEndpoints, WorkflowService1, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' and cannot act upon type 'System.ServiceModel.Description.ServiceEndpoint, System.ServiceModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'." (System.ArgumentException)
```

What my question is: Is it possible to Override the Endpoint Type to use my custom Endpoint without changing the service endpoint bindings.